# No sound out of an android MIDI driver integrated in Unity3d

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, midi

I want to output MIDI audio with Unity3d on android. Using an open source library I think I got it working but no sound is produced by the device, and there are no error messages/logs of any kind.

I am using this library:
https://github.com/billthefarmer/mididriver

I have tested the library with the provided gradle project using Android Studio and it's working well.

Unity recognizes the AAR file of this library by dropping it in Assets\Plugins\Android. I then added a java class to wrap the method calls,
 and created a small C# MonoBehaviour script to test it. I isolated the code so you can reproduce problem.

To reproduce:

1. Using Unity3d create a new 3d project.
2. Add an empty game object.
3. Attach the below C# script to it.
4. Create the folders Plugins\Android within the Assets folder.
5. Create a new file with the below java code in it, within the Android folder.
6. Add the AAR file of the latest release of the linked library.
7. build and load it to an android device.

### C# MonoBehaviour

Sends a NOTE_ON message and then a NOTE_OFF message a second later, every 2 seconds. The AndroidJavaClass is used to call the library's methods.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MidiDriverDemo : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string CLASS_PATH = "com.example.driver.AndroidMidiDriver";

    public static readonly float CYCLE_TIME_SEC = 1f;

    private float remainingTime;

    private Dictionary<int, int[]> messages;
    private int currentMessage;

    AndroidJavaClass midiDriver;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        remainingTime = CYCLE_TIME_SEC;
        currentMessage = 0;
        messages = new Dictionary<int, int[]>() {
            {  0, new int[] { 0x90, 48, 63 } },
            {  1, new int[] { 0x80, 48, 0 } }
        };

        midiDriver = new AndroidJavaClass(CLASS_PATH);
        midiDriver.Call("start");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        remainingTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(remainingTime <= 0) {
            remainingTime = CYCLE_TIME_SEC;

            midiDriver.Call("send", messages[currentMessage][0],
                messages[currentMessage][1], messages[currentMessage][2]);

            currentMessage++;
            currentMessage %= messages.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

### java Wrapper

```java
package com.example.driver;

import org.billthefarmer.mididriver.MidiDriver;

public class AndroidMidiDriver {

    private MidiDriver midi;

    public AndroidMidiDriver(){
        midi = new MidiDriver();
    }

    public void start(){
        if (midi != null) {
            midi.start();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (midi != null) {
            midi.stop();
        }
    }

    public void send(int command, int noteNumber, int velocity){
        byte[] msg = new byte[3];

        msg[0] = (byte) command;
        msg[1] = (byte) noteNumber;
        msg[2] = (byte) velocity;

        midi.write(msg);
    }
}
```

So it compiles perfectly with no warnings and is running on the device but still no sound. The sound level is properly set.

Before I isolated the problem, the call to "send" method crashed my app with segmentation fault, so something is working I guess.

So I think the problem is one of:

- This is not the correct way to access the AAR.
- I missed some setting in Unity.
- The problem is in the library itself, unlikely because it is working standalone with the provided gradle project.

Any ides/suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extracting the libmidi.so in the jni/armv7a folder from the .aar, removing the java wrapper and changing the code to the following:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class MidiDriverDemo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static readonly float CYCLE_TIME_SEC = 1f;

    private float remainingTime;

    private Dictionary<int, byte[]> messages;
    private int currentMessage;

    [DllImport("midi")]
    private static extern float midi_init();

    [DllImport("midi")]
    private static extern float midi_shutdown();

    [DllImport("midi")]
    private static extern float midi_write(byte[] msg, int length);

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        remainingTime = CYCLE_TIME_SEC;
        currentMessage = 0;
        messages = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>() {
            {  0, new byte[] { 0x90, 48, 100 } },
            {  1, new byte[] { 0x80, 48, 0 } }
        };

        midi_init();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        remainingTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(remainingTime <= 0) {
            remainingTime = CYCLE_TIME_SEC;

            midi_write(messages[currentMessage], 3);

            currentMessage++;
            currentMessage %= messages.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

There is finally audio output on the device.